# Improve performance in Excel using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

We have a single formula which we are coping to over to a defined range of over 250'000 cells. The performance of Excel clearly takes a hit. Is there a way to improve the performance by using VBA?

The formula returns either 0 or 1 as a value to the cell depending on 4 criteria. The Excel formula is:

```
=IF(NOT(ISTEXT($B9)),"",IF((L$5=""),"",IF(AND(M$5>MIN($G9,$H9),L$5<MAX($G9,$H9)),1,0)))
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: How long does this take to calculate? Usually native Excel is far better in terms of performance than VBA.

Comment: @Kyle, could you elaborate? There are questions here at SO that state otherwise.

Comment: Every cell still has to undergo this test in your 250000 range, so it very well may be 50/50 to convert to VBA. That being said, this formula could be reduced to a boolean test like: `=ISTEXT($B9) * (L$5<>"") * (M$5>MIN($G9,$H9)) * (L$5<MAX($G9,$H9))` That might be a tiny bit faster to calculate.

Comment: Which cell would this particular formula live in?  It looks like you have some columns and rows changing while others remain static.  If we know the reference cell then we could come up with some VBA to time against it.

Comment: If the `MIN($G9,$H9)` and `MAX($G9,$H9)` were moved into two extra "helper" columns, would that speed things up?  I'm thinking that it would then only have to calculate three cells (the `MIN`, the `MAX`, and the formula in the question) each time a cell in column G or H was changed, but would avoid having to do the 500,000 comparisons every time that L$5 or M$5 was changed.

Comment: @davejal, umm...not really. What I mean is you would never create your own version of `=SUM()`, because it wouldn't be faster than native Excel. That's why I asked how long this takes to calculate. I'm sure there are times when VBA can outperform, but a simple cell by cell logical comparison doesn't seem to be one of those time. Feel free to prove me wrong if you'd like.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this could be an alternative to 250,000 rows of formulas.  As stated in the comments, this still would take some time given the size of the data set.  I ran a test with a sheet that just had the necessary cells populated with 249,488 rows and the code took 12 seconds to run.  With more data in the sheet I anticipate it taking longer than that.

That said this will reduce the memory of your file significantly since there won't be any formulas:

```
Sub Run()

    Dim i As Long 'Row number for loop
    Dim lRow As Long 'Last row of data set
    Dim ms As Worksheet

    Set ms = Sheets("Sheet1") 'Change to whatever sheet you need this in

    With ms
        If .Cells(5, 12).Value = "" Then
            MsgBox "Please enter a value in Cell L5 before proceeding."
        Else
            lRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row 'This is assuming Column B is populated in full to the bottom of the data set

            For i = 9 To lRow 'This is assuming you will be starting the calculation in row 9
                If IsNumeric(.Cells(i, 2).Value) = False And .Cells(i, 2).Value <> "" Then 'Ensuring Column B is text and not blank
                    If .Cells(5, 12).Value < WorksheetFunction.Max(.Cells(i, 7).Value, .Cells(i, 8).Value) And .Cells(5, 13).Value > WorksheetFunction.Min(.Cells(i, 7).Value, .Cells(i, 8).Value) Then
                        .Cells(i, 1).Value = 1 'Assuming you want the 0 or 1 in Column A
                    Else
                        .Cells(i, 1).Value = 0 'Assuming you want the 0 or 1 in Column A
                    End If
                End If
            Next i
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

**EDIT**

Per Cornintern's awesome suggestion, I've rewritten this to use arrays instead of looping through the entire range.  This now takes less than 2 seconds:

```
Sub Run()

    Dim i As Long 'Row number for loop
    Dim lRow As Long 'Last row of data set
    Dim ms As Worksheet
    Dim mVar1() As Variant
    Dim mVar2() As Variant
    Dim mVar3() As Variant
    Dim rVar() As Variant
    Dim num1 As Long
    Dim num2 As Long

    Set ms = Sheets("Sheet1") 'Change to whatever sheet you need this in

    With ms
        If .Cells(5, 12).Value = "" Then
            MsgBox "Please enter a value in Cell L5 before proceeding."
        Else
            lRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row 'This is assuming Column B is populated in full to the bottom of the data set

            ReDim rVar(1 To lRow - 8) As Variant
            mVar1 = .Range("G9:G" & lRow)
            mVar2 = .Range("H9:H" & lRow)
            mVar3 = .Range("B9:B" & lRow)
            num1 = .Cells(5, 12).Value
            num2 = .Cells(5, 13).Value

            For i = 1 To UBound(mVar1) 'This is assuming you will be starting the calculation in row 9
                If IsNumeric(mVar3(i, 1)) = False And mVar3(i, 1) <> "" Then 'Ensuring Column B is text and not blank
                    If num1 < WorksheetFunction.Max(mVar1(i, 1), mVar2(i, 1)) And num2 > WorksheetFunction.Min(mVar1(i, 1), mVar2(i, 1)) Then
                        rVar(i) = 1
                    Else
                        rVar(i) = 0
                    End If
                End If
            Next i
        End If
    End With

    Range("A9:A" & lRow) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(rVar)
End Sub
```

Comment: You could probably cut the run time by another 80-90% by working with a value array instead of individual cell reads and writes.

Comment: Good call!  Just added an array version of this to my answer - definitely makes it a lot faster

Comment: Thanks all. This is really helpful and amazing that it has received so much feedback in such little time. Its getting late here in Switzerland, will give it a go tomorrow morning. A question if I may, the range to calculate is L9 to AOZ250,  so should we be using lCol somewhere ? Really appreciate all your help !

Comment: `Transpose` is a reasonably expensive operation.  It can be avoided by `ReDim rVal(1 to lRow - 8, 1 To 1)` and `rVal(i, 1) = ...`

Answer (score 0):

Given that your formula is simple I would expect that the formula approach would calculate faster/better than VBA:

- Excel calculates using multiple cores: VBA only uses 1
- The overhead of transferring data to VBA and back to Excel is
  substantial
- Excel can calculate over a million simple formulas per second
- Excel can automatically recalculate efficiently if any of the data
  changes, but you would have to rerun the entire VBA sub.

I would recommend seeing how long the formula approach takes in practice: I would be surprised if it calculates in more than a second.